# Could a species evolve a special organ that stores pure energy & allows it to control its own magnetic field?

Tags: biology, creature-design, evolution, energy, electromagnetism

Could a species, over centuries of evolution, evolve a special organ that stores pure energy and allows it to control its own magnetic field? What possible steps would have to happen for this to occur? Also, do you think its skin would be would be as hard as lead to contain it?

I'd like to thank everyone who answered my silly question nearly all the information you shared has been very helpful.

Comment: There is no such thing as "pure energy", that's just pseudo-sci-fi silliness. "Centuries of evolution" also betrays a certain lack of scope sensitivity on your part :) What kind of "magnetic field" do you have in mind? Fish commonly use magnetic fields to orient themselves and sense other fish in the water. If you specifically mean being able to magnetically attract stuff... how would that be any useful? Most things aren't ferromagnetic, and even those that are cannot be attracted over any meaningful distance. You need to think about the environment in which traits like this would be useful.

Comment: Like @Luaan says, pure energy is not a thing. Every energy "type" has a physical carrier of sorts. Electrons for electrical energy, molecular bonds for chemical energy etc. Energy can't be "pure", it has to be connected to some material form. And evolution works on millions of years, centuries are nothing.

Comment: It's called fat and glycogen. Most likely you even have both of them yourself. A special organ for that? What about organs that also store glycogen or fat? Seems way more intuitive. You even have a very weak magnetic field, I do not know how they are connected though. As for evolution: Since magnetic fields are mostly pretty useless biologically (yes, I'm aware of some "theories" debating about the chirality and magnetic fields) there is no way a species would evolve to control that magnetic field for no reason. "Centuries" of evolution is also laughably short unless you are very small ...

Comment: Just nitpicking about your comment, @Raditz_35, but it isn't being very small that makes centuries of evolution actually effective.  It's having a short reproductive cycle (which is almost always found in small creatures, so you I guess there is that).

Comment: @Gryphon There isn't enough space in the comments to explain every little detail. I think I made it to exactly 0 characters left. But thanks for filling that gap for me - I was actually trying to figure out how to put it in there while still keeping my comment intact but then I thought it's not worth my time anymore. I think I always look like an idiot when doing double comments

Comment: Double comments don't look stupid (IMO anyway).  It just means you have lots to say about a topic, implying you're well versed in it.

Comment: @Gryphon The mods will delete this discussion, but let's give them something to do: I personally think it's lack of skill if you can't get your message across given the restraints. I'm not good at filtering out the main problems with a post because often here the comment would be longer than the post just to list the most obvious - and I do not think this is helping anybody, especially since many posters here are kids. I'm not of the "twitter generation" as they say. Future authors will be very good at being precise.

Comment: @Raditz_35 IMO, they should extend the limit.  I do agree that pointing out the obvious problems in a post can take a ridiculous amount of space for some posts.  However, I think it's worth doing anyway.  I don't think it's a lack of skill to have to use multiple comments if you have to address a huge number of issues.  However, if you're wasting space with excessive explanation, I do agree that multiple comments look stupid.  Maybe our ideas of excessive explanation simply differ?

Comment: @Gryphon I'm just seeing that most people do not encounter this problem. I personally would also welcome more space - especially for such a stack exchange where one needs to explain regularly why a concept or idea is not solid enough to ask hard science questions about minor details

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62001/discussion-between-gryphon-and-raditz-35).

Comment: I'm chock full of pure potential energy

Comment: [Beware the unintended side effects of a creature emitting a magnetic field](http://metro.co.uk/2017/07/06/pet-hamster-stuck-to-cage-for-three-days-after-eating-fridge-magnet-6759705/)

Comment: @Luaan [Technically](https://xkcd.com/1475/), tens of thousands of centuries can still be measured in centuries.

Comment: You may want to read about electric eels.

Answer (score 50):

## Storing Energy

Surprisingly, most creatures already do this! Fats built up on the body contain [Chemical potential energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_potential), as does glucose molecules in cells. This definitely isn't storing lightning in your veins, but organic flesh isn't very good with electricity as we know it.

Fat itself contains around 9 calories per gram, which is about 37kJ of raw energy waiting to happen. 1 kilo of fat contains 37,656 kilojoules of energy. This is actually rather impressive, compared to our modern batteries, which usually contain around 360 - 900 kj/kg, human fat is a lot better at storing energy than a literal battery in your chest.

*[Comparison of Energy Densities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_density#Common_energy_densities)*

## Storing "Pure" Energy

Energy isn't something that can really be pure, but it does have a lot of forms, the one you're probably thinking of when you say "Pure" energy is probably [Electrical Energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_energy).

There are two ways to go about doing this in a "Safe" way.

The first, is to store [Electrical Potential Energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential_energy) rather than the energy itself.

This means storing the means to generate electricity, rather then the pure electricity, like a traditional battery. If you want examples of how a creature can evolve this, look no further than the [Electric Eel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_eel). It contains pairs of organs referred to as [Electric Organs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_organ_(biology)), which *essentially* uses ATP, which is cell energy, to generate electricity, much like a muscle does. In the eel, this produces either low or high voltage zaps, in this theoretical creature, it may be able to create a magnetic field. This is probably the best method, as it's the safest, and uses the body's already supple energy to charge.

The second is to actually store electricity itself in a highly conductive organ, preferably a 100% efficient conductor, surrounded tightly by insulation. Both of these factors are highly important, and are likely reasons that an organ like this wouldn't evolve. If the conductor isn't conductive enough, power will drain from the system slowly, and the organ will unnaturally heat up. If the insulator isn't effective, the power could leak, and potentially stop the creature's heart. This doesn't even go into the idea of how one would charge the battery.

## Magnetic Field Control

Now, Magnetic Fields can't really be stopped, there's nothing really practical that can be done to reduce the passive magnetic field that organisms put out, but it's theoretically possible for a creature to create their own stronger magnetic field.

Electricity flowing through a wire (or a particularly conductive organ) will generate a magnetic field no matter what, which is why [Magnetroception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetoreception) can be used to detective movement of living things, But if you want a particularly strong magnetic field, you'd need to move a lot of electricity through a small space, usually a coil; This is the concept of an [Electromagnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnet).

If the creature can produce a sort of organic wire, probably from a mineral like iron, it would be possible to coil it up somewhere, and send power from the previously mentioned energy storage methods through it. This comes with many of the similar risks as the lightning box did, that is, energy leaks could stop the heart, or the tissue not being conductive enough wasting energy, but it is theoretically evolutionarily possible.

### Evolution of a Magnet Organ.

For a creature to evolve something, [it needs to be useful](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sAGEOKAG0zw) early in it's development; evolution isn't particular fast, and it does not favor the useless. But if the world this creature lives on is incredibly rich in a [ferromagnetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferromagnetism) mineral, so much so that most creatures are digesting it, it could be favourable for a creature to generate their own weak magnetic current, to pull food towards them, and that in the like, although this is a bit of a stretch.

It seems the most probable way for a creature to evolve this organ, is for it to first evolve the organ required for electrical production, probably to shock prey much like our eel friend, and then from there adapt it to magnetisation, for some unknown gain.

*Citations provided where possible, much of this is speculation*

Comment: This actually seems really plausible, and I love it. Please rush me my tractor-beam equipped eels. Also the answer is just a superb answer in general.

Comment: The magnetic field generated could be used to confuse creatures using magnetroception, trapping/confusing homing pigeons or similar.

Comment: How do you like my ferromagnetic stretch? :D It pulls food forward, but not in the way you probably had in mind.

Comment: Since mitochondria store and actively pump protons (Hydrogen ions) between two membranes for use as the cell's energy source, I don't think that electricity storage or charging the battery are problems at all. That's exactly how you work already!

Comment: If the creature is aquatic and needs to consume on iron or iron heavy pray, a magnetic field could be used as a way to pull and filter iron out of the water without the creature producing much physical movement.

Comment: If it's a filter feeder, it pulls things in a slow current. If it has pray that builds little shells out of little iron bits, it might use an electromagnet pulse to pull them quickly to the mouth so the teeth can then grab it.

Comment: @Jacobm001 The thing is, few iron compounds are actually magnetic. Most of the iron in e.g. humans isn't ferromagnetic. The main exception being the parts actually used by animals for magnetic sensing (the homing pigeons Wil noted). And it's a lot easier to biologically use compounds that readily dissolve in water - it's our main supply mechanism, after all.

Comment: Don't forget glycogen *"Glycogen is a multibranched polysaccharide of glucose that serves as a form of energy storage in humans"*  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycogen - Edit - I see that Raditz mentioned this in a comment.